# Unit Testing Oracle Stored Procedure with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: oracle, unit-testing

I used Visual Studio 2010 to create database unit tests for some stored procedures that returns multiple rows.  In SQL Server it was easy, I just executed the stored procedure (EXEC MyProcedure 9999) and the rows were automatically returned so I could use the test designer to check the resultset.

Now I’m trying to write the same tests for Oracle; however, the Oracle stored procedure uses a cursor output parameter to return the results.    For example the signature of the stored procedures looks like:

```
PROCEDURE MyProcedure
(
    v_ItemId   IN NUMBER,
    io_cursor  IN OUT t_cursor
) AS...
```

Because it takes a cursor as a parameter, I need to declare one in my test.  Looking at other questions posted on this subject, I was able to create this:

```
DECLARE
   refcsr  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   MyProcedure (9999, refcsr); 
END;
```

I know the refcsr contains my results, but my question is how do I make the contents of the cursor visible as a result set to Visual Studio testing framework?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
variable x refcursor
exec MyProcedure(9999, :x)
print x
```

Comment: Its probably my total lack of knowledge with Oracle, but I've tried that and I can never get Oracle to accept the syntax. Take the first line for example, `variable x refcursor` gives me 'ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement'.

Comment: The above needs to be run in sqlplus. I assumed you wanted to run it as a unit test. SQL scripts are best suited for this task.

Comment: I'm using the unit test framework within Visual Studio which connects to the database via ODP.NET.